# Platform support for arbitrary codecs in HEIF

Tags: iso, video-codecs, image-formats, heif

Apparently, the hip way to define a new image format is to combine the [ISO base media file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_base_media_file_format) with an existing image or intra-frame video codec, generalized in [HEIF / MIAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) with existing explicit HEVC, AVC and AV1 adaptations. JPEG 2000 employs ISOBMMF in a different way.

Can I expect platforms (i.e. operating systems, browsers, ...) that support HEIF in general and a random codec in general to support the specific combination of both as well? or does every codec need custom boxes/atoms?

For instance, could I simply put VP8 or VP9 streams, as known from WebM and WebP, into a HEIF container? or more ancient, exotic or futuristic video codecs like MPEG-1/2, ASP, Ogg Theora, Daala, Thor, Dirac, Cineform, VVC, EVC? What about JPEG XL/XR/XT/LS/2K, PNG or even BMP/RLE still images?